# SQLite query to get SUM of values between two dates on regular time intervals

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to get sums of the values between two dates on regular intervals by SQLite query.

Let's say, that table looks like that:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22:04:02 | 22:04:12 | 8 |
| 22:04:12 | 22:04:22 | 22 |
| 22:04:22 | 22:04:32 | 10 |
| 22:04:32 | 22:04:42 | 9 |
| 22:04:42 | 22:04:52 | 92 |
| 22:04:52 | 22:05:02 | 14 |
| 22:05:02 | 22:05:12 | 88 |
| 22:05:12 | 22:05:22 | 24 |
| 22:05:22 | 22:05:32 | 30 |

I came up to about something like that

`SELECT SUM(Col3) AS duomenys FROM myTable`
`WHERE Col1 >= '22:04:02' AND Col2 <= '22:05:02' GROUP BY Time(Col1, '+20 seconds')`

but result is `SUM` of all data in `Col3` between those two times - 155.

My desired result would be:

| Time | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 22:04:22 | 30 |
| 22:04:42 | 19 |
| 22:05:02 | 106 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xFxuYCP4)

Comment: Why are you adding 20 seconds to the col1 time in the group by?

Comment: @Shawn Because i want to devide full range into portions (e.g. 20 seconds), and get the sum of Col3 of all vaues in those portions.

Comment: Group by groups rows with the same value for its expression(s), not ranges...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that:-

```
SELECT sum(col3) AS duomenys FROM mytable WHERE Col1 >= '22:04:02' AND Col2 <= '22:05:02' GROUP BY ((strftime('%s',col1) / 20))
```

Will do as you wish, as per:-

[image]

- **this does assume grouping based upon every 20 seconds starting from 00 seconds.**